# Can I use h:messages to display error message next to commandbutton?

Tags: jsf

While I tried doing that, the following code results in 'There are some unhandled FacesMessages...'
I want to give the users the number of rows of data that were imported. I am not using PrimeFaces, only basic JSF.

```
<h:commandButton type="submit" value="Import" id="NumberRows"
                action="#{actionBeanFile.processDataImport}" />
                 <h:message for="NumberRows" errorClass="errorMessage" />
```

The code in the processDataImport() method is

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("myform:NumberRows", new FacesMessage("The number of rows imported is " + Integer.toString(numberRows)));
```

Comment: Are you sure about that id you're using? Have you tried just `NumberRows`? As a catch-all, you could just use `<h:messages/>` which displays all messages, regardless of id

Answer (score 0):

The `<h:messages />` tag is to be used for displaying validation error.
To display a notification message you can use the tag `<h:outputLabel />`

Comment: <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Import"
    action="#{actionBeanFile.processDataImport}" />
   <h:outputLabel rendered="#{actionFileBean.fileImportError}" value="#{actionBeanFile.Message}"></h:outputLabel>

This was the code I used initially. actionBeanFile.processDataImport returns the same jsp page. And actionBeanFile.Message fetches the number of rows.

But for some reason the actionBeanFile.Message is not displayed

Comment: Did you set to true the property actionFileBean.fileImportError inside the method actionBeanFile.processDataImport? Anyway, inside the action attribute you have written actionBeanFile but inside the rendered attribute you have written actionFileBean, is this an error?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the overlook, I will change it. It should work. Because the fileImportError is set as true in the method